# Is there a way to zoom and then do a selection interval without further zooming with vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

Have a scatter plot, I know you use bind on the scales for panning and using the wheel to zoom which is great.  However once zoomed need a way to then do a selection interval without further zooming effects. Need a way to pause or escape via a shift key for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use an event modifier in the selection definition. For example, here is a chart where the zoom action is triggered when the shift key is not held, and the selection action is triggered when the shift key is held ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA28QAspQA4Gc4B6IgNwFMBzCAOkoEspNEAjG+gezKogFpIY+clHxEBEIgGMIyfDQBW+DgDsQAXwA0IALYyA1hlwd6yqCC3llkjmBOV4oa6g7IHIKAE9c5DMo7aTCHQtADN6clQwDAB5ZHoGVU0QAA83T28MAEdECFNGaHoKcxAwiKi4EAAJFyEjAHdyVySPNK8fCuzcqHzuotDwyIwAWXpUcnwAfW9kCYBxIOdEpKExyW6VNwAvDn9WjIqTKEbSIOKWE3KQfGkx-GKNioBtbQ5EITAOOuVHgEJyClMNHwmHoISgAGlyB4ALoaAAELze5EQuGhcIAfAjXkIXn13MhcvhUNB2iBntjyB8vr9-pYoECQWDITD4YihCi0Zi2eRceQfuotCtyGs9qTDsdTloHmTuVTvrTAcDQRCobCsUiORj1TiOHioATlESSRhyUi5Y8FfSlUzVayKZquRTefy1K6gA)):

```json
{
  "data": {"url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Origin"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Horsepower"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Miles_per_Gallon"}
  },
  "selection": {
    "zoom": {
      "type": "interval",
      "bind": "scales",
      "on": "[mousedown[!event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
      "translate": "[mousedown[!event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!"
    },
    "select": {
      "type": "interval",
      "on": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
      "translate": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!"
    }
  }
}
```

The syntax here follows [vega eventStream selectors](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/event-streams/#selector).

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Altair as well?