# Is there a way to zoom and then do a selection interval without further zooming with Altair

Tags: altair

Have a scatter plot, I know you use bind on the scales for panning and using the wheel to zoom which is great. However once zoomed need a way to then do a selection interval without further zooming effects. Need a way to pause or escape via a shift key for example. In the [vega-lite question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993712/is-there-a-way-to-zoom-and-then-do-a-selection-interval-without-further-zooming) it uses mouse events.  There is no example at all of how to do this in Altair documentation. The API is there however the `altair.EventType` does not expose the mouse events.

Very much appreciate how to get this to work in Altair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using an event modifier in the selection definition (there are a few examples in Altair's docs [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#composing-multiple-selections)).

For example, here is a chart where the zoom action is triggered when the shift key is not held, and the selection action is triggered when the shift key is held:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

zoom = alt.selection_interval(
    bind='scales',
    on="[mousedown[!event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
    translate="[mousedown[!event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!",
)

selection = alt.selection_interval(
    on="[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
    translate="[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!",
)

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
).add_selection(zoom, selection)
```

The syntax for these event modifiers can be found in vega's [eventStream selector](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/event-streams/#selector) documentation.